# Как перезапустить mongodb и добавить к ноде replSet?

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, config, systemctl

У меня есть нода primary 5.0.2 На порту 27017. Хочу добавить к ней replSet. Запускаю команду:

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

Далее в конфигурационный файл добавил:

```
replication:
  replSetName: "secondaries"
```

Затем Запустил

```
sudo systemctl deamon-reload
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Вошел в базу и получил сведения о конфигурации:

```
mongosh -u user
use admin
switched to db admin
admin>  db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")
{
  argv: [
    '/usr/bin/mongod',
    '--config',
    'path/to/datadir/сonf/mongod.cfg',
    '--port',
    '27017'
  ],
  parsed: {
    config: 'path/to/datadir/conf/mongod.cfg',
    net: { bindIp: 'xxx.x.xxx.x, 127.0.0.1', port: 27017 },
    security: {
      authorization: 'enabled',
      keyFile: '/path/to/keyfile'
    },
    storage: { dbPath: '/path/to/db' },
    systemLog: {
      destination: 'file',
      path: '/path/to/log'
    }
  },
```

Все пути и хост скрыты мной. Как видите, в файле конфигурации нет ничего про поле replication. Как правильно добавить эту опцию? Возможно я перезапустил не тот сервис?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replication нужно добавить в файл, как отдельную секцию:

```
replication:
  replSetName: "secondaries"
```

Перезапустить сервис мне помогли команды

```
sudo /usr/bin/mongod --config /path/to/conf/mongod.cfg --port 27017 --shutdown
sudo /usr/bin/mongod --config /path/to/conf/mongod.cfg --port 27017 &>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 1):

В `mongod.cfg` добавь опцию `replication` в секцию `systemLog`

```
systemLog:
  replication:
    replSetName: "secondaries"
```

Потом перезапусти `mongod`

```
sudo systemctl stop mongod
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

Comment: После добавления в systemlog опция тоже не появилась. На машине есть еще ноды, возможно они мешают при start-stop командах?